# Prove that the following power series convergent when |x|<1.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(n+1)x^n}$$

I tried to use the ratio test but I messed up something along the way. According to an online calculator the statement is true but I need to prove it. Could you help me or hint me how to do it?

Comment: $$a_n=(n+1) x^n \implies \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right|\,|x|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the ratio test works here.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1+1)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)x^n}$ seems quite straight forward. Perhaps you didn't get this?

This simplifies down to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1+1)x}{(n+1)}$.

Using properties of rational functions, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+2)}{(n+1)} = 1$ (horizontal asymptote). We are then left with $x$.

The problem gives us that $|x| \lt 1$, so the ratio test has given us a value below $1$. Therefore this converges.

Comment: I didn't knew about the horizontal asymptote and stopped there.  (Over complicating things is my great ability, really trivial but thanks a lot!